# Android webview click button using jquery

Tags: android, jquery

I am loading some website in my android application using `WebView` and what I just want to do is after loading the page I want to automatically click the `<button>` with `data-stage="premium"`

here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="switch-stage">
            <div>
                <button data-stage="normal">Normal</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button data-stage="premium">Premium</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#switch-stage button').on('click', function() {
                var stage = $(this).data('stage');
            });     
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is what I've done in android.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"switch-stage button\").click(\"premium\");");
```

but I think my `loadUrl` is not correct. (This is what I am seeing in different link that I've searched.)

Is it possible to do what I am asking, to automatically click the `button` so that the `var stage` will have a data.?

I hope someone will help, Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to click your desired button on every page load?

Comment: @MuhmmadAbubakarIkram Yes.

Comment: Then why don't you run a js function on every page load? rather than clicking a button on every page load.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        // hide element by id LECLERC
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementsById('Premium').click();" 
        //document.getElementById("switch-stage").children[1].click();
    ;})()");

    }
```